# ExtJS fieldset not working post sencha command build

Tags: extjs, cmd, extjs4, fieldset

I am using a collapsible fieldset which seems to be working fine on my Dev environment as below :

[image: Without Sencha Build]

**Generated Code:**

```
<legend id="fieldset-1041-legend" class="x-fieldset-header x-fieldset-header-default"><span role="presentation" style="display:table;" id="fieldset-1041-legend-outerCt"><div role="presentation" class="" style="display:table-cell;height:100%;vertical-align:top;" id="fieldset-1041-legend-innerCt"><div id="fieldset-1041-legendToggle" style="width:15px;height:15px;" class="x-tool x-tool-default"><img role="presentation" class="x-tool-img x-tool-toggle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" id="fieldset-1041-legendToggle-toolEl"></div><div id="fieldset-1041-legendTitle" class="x-component x-fieldset-header-text x-fieldset-header-text-collapsible x-component-default">My Fieldset</div></div></span></legend>
```

But when I perform build using Sencha command (v4.2.2), I don't get the required icon and collapsible behavior as shown below:

> Please note that text **My** is coming truncated and is covered by the
>   collapse icon

[image]

**Generated Code:**

```
<legend id="fieldset-1142-legend" class="x-fieldset-header x-fieldset-header-default"><span role="presentation" style="display:table;" id="fieldset-1142-legend-outerCt"><div role="presentation" class="" style="display:table-cell;height:100%;vertical-align:top;" id="fieldset-1142-legend-innerCt"><div id="fieldset-1142-legendToggle" style="border-width:1px;width:15px;height:15px;" class="x-column-header x-column-header-align-center x-column-header-default x-unselectable"><div class="x-column-header-inner x-column-header-inner-empty" role="presentation" id="fieldset-1142-legendToggle-titleEl" style="padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px;"><span class="x-column-header-text" id="fieldset-1142-legendToggle-textEl">&nbsp;</span><div class="x-column-header-trigger" role="presentation" id="fieldset-1142-legendToggle-triggerEl" style=""></div></div></div><div id="fieldset-1142-legendTitle" class="x-component x-fieldset-header-text x-fieldset-header-text-collapsible x-component-default">My Fieldset</div></div></span></legend>
```

I can notice the differences in the generated code e.g. the working one uses classes like -

```
x-tool-img x-tool-toggle
```

whereas in the later case I see classes like -

```
x-column-header x-column-header-align-center x-column-header-default x-unselectable
```

PLEASE HELP. I request you to please provide any hints possible that I can try.

Thanks :)

Comment: Check if you get any "Synchronous loading" warnings in dev environment. If yes, fix all of them and re-build.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. This is a very good point and i have solve problems like these in the past using this technique but unfortunately it seems to be a different problem. I created a simple fieldset with collapsible feature and that worked on both DEV and TEST(Sencha Build) but the problem comes when that fieldset is within a collapsible panel inside an Ext Window. Any idea what could be going wrong? If there are any structural issues like these then why does it work with ext-all-dev.js? any idea?

Comment: Jagpreet, I cannot say more on it that could be anyhow helpful without seeing it in action. It can be Ext problem/bug, Sencha Cmd bug and you app bug as well.